# Chef wait for resource start

Tags: chef-infra, grafana

I'm executing the following recipe:

```
include_recipe 'grafana::default'

grafana_datasource 'InfluxDB' do
  source(
    type: 'influxdb',
    url: 'http://localhost:8086',
    access: 'proxy',
    database: 'living',
    isdefault: true
  )
  action :create
end
```

grafana::default install the grafana service and then the grafana_datasource installs a new datasource on that grafana. The problem is that grafana is still not started when I try to execute grafana_datasource and it crashes.

How I can subscribe to grafana service and execute that grafana_datasource code after service has completely started?

Comment: you may just add `retries 3` and `retry_delay 10` in the grafana_datasource as described [here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#properties)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specifically in Chef for this. You could use the generic `retries` as mentioned by Tensibai or you could use a `ruby_block` resource that waits until the service is up and responsive. Most service layers (Upstart, systemd, etc) are asynchronous so Chef's `service` resource (and related things) will block on sending the start/restart command but that doesn't mean the service will actually be up and running after that. This usually takes the form of:

```
ruby_block 'wait_until_up' do
  block do
    while true
      if try_to_connect()
        break
      end
      sleep 10
    end
  end
end
```

or something like that.